# ExtJS, how to override parent class button names and handlers from child class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a parent class and child class as mentioned below.

```
Ext.ns("MyUi");
MyUi.ParentPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
initComponent: function() {
    MyUiPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
},
id: 'card-id',
layout: 'card',
activeItem: 0,
buttonAlign: 'center',
buttons:[{
            text: "Next", 
            id: "card-next", 
            handler:  function(){
                Ext.getCmp('card-id').navigationHandler(1);
            }
        },{
            text: "Previous", 
            id: "card-prev", 
            handler: function(){
                Ext.getCmp('card-id').navigationHandler(-1);
            },
            disabled: true
        },{
            text: "Finish", 
            id: "finishButton", 
        }],
navigationHandler: function(increment){
         //code to switch cards/items
}});

var panel1 = ...
var panel2 = ...

childPanel = Ext.extend(MyUi.ParentPanel, {
    initComponent: function() {
        var items = [panel1, panel2];
        Ext.apply( this, {
            items: items
        });
        Cx.Ui.ProvisionRPoolWizardPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this);
    }
```

});

I want my child panel to override to parent panel button names and handlers.

For example, instead of 'Finish' I want to have name called "Complete" in child panel and I want to have its own handler.

And child panel should be able override parent panel "Next" handler code. For example, when I am on panel1, if I click 'Next', I want to do some 
validations, and then I want to call parent panel's "Next" handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why simply not create your child-specific buttons in `initComponent`, for example:

```
childPanel = Ext.extend(MyUi.ParentPanel, {
    initComponent: function() {
        var items = [panel1, panel2];
        Ext.apply( this, {
            items: items
        });
        this.buttons = [{
            text: "Next", 
            id: "card-next", 
            handler:  function(){
               //your new handler here
            }
        },{
            text: "Previous", 
            id: "card-prev", 
            handler: function(){
                Ext.getCmp('card-id').navigationHandler(-1);
            },
            disabled: true
        },{
            text: "Complete", 
            id: "finishButton", 
        }];
        Cx.Ui.ProvisionRPoolWizardPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this);
});
```